# Sphinx usage with Matlab does not generate documentation (sphinxcontrib.matlab)

Tags: python, matlab, documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I am currently developing a MATLAB toolbox as part of my bachelors at TUM, that I would like to document using the automatic documentation in Sphinx.

There is a extension available for just that [here](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain). However I am having problems getting this to work.

The index.html does not contain anything other than the content of the index.rst in the source directory. Also, Sphinx does not throw any error.

I am using sphinx version 5.0.0 as `sphinxcontrib.matlab` was tested for sphinx versions >= 4.0.0 and <6.0.0

The overall directory structure is as follows:

```
C:\Users\lelem\TUM\Semester\WS2223\BachelorThesisSVN\07_Software

├───CalibrationDataSets
│   └───Hiding Place
├───crossedHotWireCalibrationSubfunctions
├───docs
│   ├───build
│   │   ├───.doctrees
│   │   ├───_sources
│   │   └───_static
│   └───source
│       ├───_static
│       └───_templates
├───Preexisting Software
└───temp
crossedHotWireCalibration.m
```

- `C:\Users\lelem\TUM\Semester\WS2223\BachelorThesisSVN\07_Software\crossedHotWireCalibration.m` is the main matlab function that is the body of the toolbox.
- In `C:\Users\lelem\TUM\Semester\WS2223\BachelorThesisSVN\07_Software\crossedHotWireCalibrationSubfunctions` subfunctions that are called by main.m are located.
- In `C:\Users\lelem\TUM\Semester\WS2223\BachelorThesisSVN\07_Software\CalibrationDataSets` result data of `crossedHotWireCalibration.m` is stored in .mat files

The contents of docs have been generated by `sphinx-quickstart` enabling seperation of the source and build directories.

From the README of `sphinxcontrib.matlab` I understand that changes to `conf.py` have do be made.

1. specify extensions (I want to use the matlab domain, have automatic documentation generation and caller and call graphs). Thus: `extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.matlab', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.graphviz']`
2. The code I wish to document is not in `./docs/source` but at `C:\Users\lelem\TUM\Semester\WS2223\BachelorThesisSVN\07_Software`. Thus: `matlab_src_dir = 'C:/Users/lelem/TUM/Semester/WS2223/BachelorThesisSVN/07_Software`

The `conf.py` in `./docs/source` looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# import os

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = 'X Hot Wire Calibration and Data Evaluation'
copyright = '2023, Leander Merbecks'
author = 'Leander Merbecks'
release = '0.1'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinxcontrib.matlab', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.graphviz']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []

# this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('07_Software'))
# matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(this_dir, '..'))
matlab_src_dir = 'C:/Users/lelem/TUM/Semester/WS2223/BachelorThesisSVN/07_Software'


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Now I would expect that the `index.html` contains the comments in `crossedHotWireCalibration.m` directly placed under the header. Basically the same as if I was calling `help crossedHotWireCalibration`. However upon opening `index.html` I see nothing but the elements specified in `index.rst`.

The contents of the `index.rst` are here

```
.. X Hot Wire Calibration documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Mar 17 12:46:58 2023.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to X Hot Wire Calibration's documentation!
==================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

There are no

Comment: To get some meaningful output, you need to use at least one of the auto-directives listed here: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain#roles-and-directives

Comment: I tried that with the .. automodule:: directive, while also specifying a module. Also tried .. autofunction::. Both methods were futile...
However I think this defeats the purpose of automatic documentation...

Comment: Defeats the purpose? There seems to be some misunderstanding here. You have to use automodule/autofunction or similar directives. That's the whole point.

Comment: But wait that means say I have 100 functions in my project I need to call all of them with the autofunction directive?

Comment: No, if they are in a module, then you only need to use `automodule` once. The point is that it is not enough to just specify `matlab_src_dir`. You have to tell Sphinx what you want to document. I know quite well how to use Sphinx for documenting Python code. However, I am not very familiar with MATLAB, and I have never used the sphinxcontrib.matlab extension. So there might be MATLAB-related nuances that I am not aware of.

Comment: I'm the author of the extension you are trying to use: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain, you are very welcome to post an issue there if you need more help. I think you could solve your issue with `.. automodule:: name` and then use a the :member: option.